# Asus - HDMI black screen on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

HDMI is detected, but screen 2 is black

nvidia-bug-report.log
https://pastebin.com/t5Gx9ixW

```
intelipower                 
    descripción: Notebook
    producto: TUF Gaming FX505DD_FX505DD
    fabricante: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    versión: 1.0
    serie: K7NRCV05D38931D
    anchura: 64 bits
    capacidades: smbios-3.2.1 dmi-3.2.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuración: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=TUF Gaming uuid=9F3E24EA-1B06-40C9-B864-3DABBD95217D
  *-pnp00:00
       producto: PnP device PNP0c01
       id físico: 1
       capacidades: pnp
       configuración: driver=system
  *-pnp00:01
       producto: PnP device PNP0b00
       id físico: 2
       capacidades: pnp
       configuración: driver=rtc_cmos
  *-pnp00:02
       producto: PnP device PNP0c02
       id físico: 3
       capacidades: pnp
       configuración: driver=system
```

```
$ xrandr --verbose

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  60874
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0038702d0000000000
        011c010495221378036850985c588e28
        1b505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101011a3680a070381f403020
        350058c21000001a1a3680a070384942
        3020350058c21000001a000000fd0028
        3c43430e010a202020202020000000fe
        004c4d3135364c462d434c30330a00e7
    vrr_capable: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
    abm level: 0 
        range: (0, 4)
    max bpc: 8 
        range: (8, 16)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 64 
        supported: 64
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x45) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1920x1080 (0x46) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1665           clock  39.99Hz
  1680x1050 (0x47) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x1024 (0x48) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1440x900 (0x49) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  900 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x800 (0x4a) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  800 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x720 (0x4b) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  720 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1024x768 (0x4c) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  768 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  800x600 (0x4d) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   800 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  600 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  640x480 (0x4e) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  480 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
```

```
$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display

*-display NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] [10DE:1C91]
       fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       versión: a1
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:f6000000-f6ffffff memoria:c0000000-cfffffff memoria:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memoria:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Picasso [1002:15D8]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
       versión: c2
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuración: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       recursos: irq:55 memoria:e0000000-efffffff memoria:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memoria:f7500000-f757ffff
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Xrandr detects the monitor on hdmi, but doesn't work, the only thing I can see is a blank screen.

I posted it on Launchpad --------------- 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-440/+bug/1871721


On askubuntu too ----------- 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229730/nvidia-ubuntu-20-04-hdmi-second-monitor-with-blank-screen-but-xrandr-detect

PD: I vote +1 to your question, let's see of someone can help us.