# 2nd screen detected but black (Xubuntu 20.04, Nvidia gpu)

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, xubuntu, screen

Good evening everybody, I'm a beginner on Ubuntu. I almost successfully installed Xubuntu 20.04. I say almost because I'm not able to make my external screen work. It has been difficult to mke it recognised (Nvidia driver 455 was just unable to do it). I downgraded to the driver 450 : screen recognised but black.

Does anyone have a solution ? Don't hesitate if you need more specific hints.

Hope the followings can help :)

Best regards,

Jimmy

```
    j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ lspci -vnn | grep -A12 '\''[030[02]\]' | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|kernel"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1f95] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir [1002:1636] (rev c7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$

j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ uname -a
Linux s-Nitro-AN515-44 5.8.0-33-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 17:01:13 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ 

j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+
   1680x1050     60.01  
   1280x1024     60.01  
   1440x900      60.01  
   1280x800      60.01  
   1280x720      60.01  
   1024x768      60.01  
   800x600       60.01  
   640x480       60.01  
HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ 

j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                                       Version                               Architecture Description
+++-=========================================-=====================================-============-======================================================================================================
rc  libnvidia-compute-455:amd64               455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                2.7.18-1~20.04                        amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic              5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic              5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic            5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-54-generic            5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic      5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-54-generic      5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.4.0-54-generic 5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-54
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-455                  455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-455                           455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-455                  455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  python2.7-minimal                         2.7.18-1~20.04                        amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ 

j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-450:amd64                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-450                      450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-450:amd64               450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-450:i386                450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-455:amd64               455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-450:amd64                450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-450:i386                 450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-450:amd64                450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-450:i386                 450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-450:amd64                 450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450:amd64                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386                   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-450:amd64                    450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-450:i386                     450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450:amd64                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386                   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.4.0-54-generic 5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-54
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.4.0-58-generic 5.4.0-58.64                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-58
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-450                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-455                  455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-450                           450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-455                           455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-430                         440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-440
ii  nvidia-driver-440                         450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-450
ii  nvidia-driver-450                         450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-450                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-455                  455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-450                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                              0.8.14                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                           440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-450                          450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                   0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450             450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$
```

config : Acer Nitro 5 AN515-44 | Xubuntu 20.04 | XFCE 4.14 | Kernel 5.8.0-33 | AMD Ryzen 5 4600H | 8 Go | GTX 1650 TI (4 Go), AMD Radeon Vega 6 et Optimus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening,

I found my answer here :
[nvidia-ubuntu-20-04-hdmi-second-monitor-with-blank-screen-but-xrandr-detect](http://%5Dhttps://askubuntu.com/questions/1229730/nvidia-ubuntu-20-04-hdmi-second-monitor-with-blank-screen-but-xrandr-detect)

I have to say I have not understood the final aim of the following modifications but locked for locked, I tried, even if I risked to have to reinstall everything.

I "just" need to modify the files 10-amdgpu.conf and 10-nvidia.conf located here /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
First, you need to be authorized to write in these files :

```
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ sudo chmod o+w /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ sudo chmod o+w /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
```

Then :

Open the file 10-amdgpu.conf, replace the line *Driver "amdgpu"* by *Driver "modesetting"* and save.

Open the file 10-nvidia.conf, add the line *Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"* just before the line *EndSection* and save.

Hope it will help someone else !

If someone has an explanation about the final aim of the modified/added lines, I'm interested. I'd like to learn to fish :)

Have a good night,

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I am not an advanced user myself, but I may be able to help.

First of all: how did you install the drivers? Did you use *Software & Updates*'s "Additional Drivers" tab?

Secondly: did you check which GPU is active? To do so, use `prime-select query` in the terminal. To switch to the discrete GPU, use `sudo prime-select nvidia`. On some distributions, you need to logout and login back to apply the change, or even reboot.

And, finally: does the issue persist regardless of the selected GPU?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Here is what cmd gives `j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$ prime-select query
nvidia j@j-Nitro-AN515-44:~$`. I did not you use Software & Updates's "Additional Drivers" tab to install drivers, it was already there. But I use this tb to select the driver I want. I tested nvidia-driver-440, 450 and 455.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a reply on your solution, so: did you try using `sudo prime-select nvidia` followed by a reboot? I assume it would work, too, and it is a lot easier.