# Second monitor enters power saving mode after 5 seconds

Tags: display, suspend, hdmi, dvi

I have Dell Xps 9310 and Dell 22" monitor plugged in via DVI-to-HDMI and HDMI-to-USB C.

I can use the external monitor with the same cable/connection on Windows without problem, but on Ubuntu 20.04, the external monitor displays whole start up and when I enter my password and open the system, the monitor shows the display just for 5 seconds and then enters into the power saving mode.
I found a similar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229730/nvidia-ubuntu-20-04-hdmi-second-monitor-with-blank-screen-but-xrandr-detect) but I couldn't solve this problem:

my xrandr -q output:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1317, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 288mm x 180mm
1920x1200     59.95*+  59.88    47.96
1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93
1600x1200     60.00
1680x1050     59.95    59.88
1600x1024     60.17
1400x1050     59.98
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
1280x1024     60.02
1440x900      59.89
1400x900      59.96    59.88
1280x960      60.00
1440x810      60.00    59.97
1368x768      59.88    59.85
1360x768      59.80    59.96
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
1152x864      60.00
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
1024x768      60.04    60.00
960x720       60.00
928x696       60.05
896x672       60.01
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
960x600       59.93    60.00
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
840x525       60.01    59.88
864x486       59.92    59.57
800x512       60.17
700x525       59.98
800x450       59.95    59.82
640x512       60.02
720x450       59.89
700x450       59.96    59.88
640x480       60.00    59.94
720x405       59.51    58.99
684x384       59.88    59.85
680x384       59.80    59.96
640x400       59.88    59.98
576x432       60.06
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
512x384       60.00
512x288       60.00    59.92
480x270       59.63    59.82
400x300       60.32    56.34
432x243       59.92    59.57
320x240       60.05
360x202       59.51    59.13
320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1680x1050+0+267 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
1680x1050     59.95*+
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1152x864      75.00
1024x768      75.03    60.00
800x600       75.00    60.32
640x480       75.00    59.94
720x400       70.08
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

As you can see, Ubuntu detects two displays: DP-1 and DP-3. How can I make my external monitor (DP-3) display the screen continuously?

Comment: It reads like the 2 adapters are chained together?

Comment: yes, my computer has not HDMI input, that's why I am using hdmi to usb c. But chaining is not a problem on windows